# How to serve files from IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: .net, windows, iis, iis-6

I have files with extensions like ".dae" , ".gtc" , etc. When I try to hit these files over http, the server returns a 404, but they are in the directories. However I can serve readily known file extensions; if i just rename them to say, xml, they are accessible.

Any suggestions for what the problem may be?

Answer (score 4):

If you request a file with an extension that is **not a defined MIME type on your IIS 6.0 Web server**, you receive a "*HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found*" error message.

To **define a MIME type for a specific extension**  (.dae in your case), follow these steps:

- Open the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC), **right-click the local computer name**, and then click **Properties**.
- Click **MIME Types**.
- Click **New**.
- In the Extension box, type the **file name extension** that you want (in your case **.dae**).
- In the **MIME Type box**, type *application/octet-stream*.
- **Apply** the new settings.

Note: **you must restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service** or wait for the  worker process to recycle for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define additional MIME types on IIS 6 for the extensions that you mentioned.

Here is the MS article on how to add additional MIME types to IIS6:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965